# logback where init the encoder field?

Tags: logback, encoder

Can someone tell me where the logback init the encoder field in 
OutputStreamAppender?

```
appender name="logstash" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>test.json</file>
        <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder">
            <providers>
                <timestamp>
                    <timeZone>UTC</timeZone>
                </timestamp>
            <pattern>
                <pattern>
                    {
                        "severity": "%level"
                    }
                </pattern>
            </pattern>
            </providers>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
```

Answer (score 0):

Each appender is instantiated via an invocation on `ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction`, the AppenderAction's `end()` method calls `start()` on the actual appender

For appender's which extend `OutputStreamAppender` this involves a call to `OutputStreamAppender.setOutputStream()` which in turn invokes `OutputStreamAppender.encoderInit()`.

- For `ConsoleAppender`, `setOutputStream()` is invoked directly from `start()`
- For `FileAppender`, `start()` invokes `openFile()` which then invokes `setOutputStream()`

So, in summary, Logback invokes `encoderInit()` via the `start()` method on any `Appender` which extends `OutputStreamAppender`.

Comment: Thanks for help, if i don't want to extends the OutputStreamAppender, i want to implement by myself, but always get the error "ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@15:26 - no applicable action for [pattern], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][appender][encoder][pattern]]", so how can i fix this.

Comment: Ok, that changes the question slightly. Could you perhaps update the question showing us what you have done and describing your desired outcome. See [this link for details on how to create a MVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).